# How do I fix this Prediction "mismatch" problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

After running the sequent code:

```
#Training loop
torch.manual_seed(42)
epochs = 200

for epoch in range(epochs):
  model_1.train()

  #1. Forward pass
  y_pred = model_1(X_train)

  #2. Calculate the loss
  loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)

  #3.Optimizer zero grad
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  #4. perform backpropagation
  loss.backward()

  #5. Optimizer step
  optimizer.step()

  ###Testing
  model_1.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
    test_pred = model_1(X_test)

    test_loss = loss_fn(test_pred, y_test)

  #Print what is happening
  if epoch%10 ==0:
    print(f"EPOCH:{epoch} | LOSS:{loss} | TEST LOSS:{test_loss}")

#I get this output:

EPOCH:0 | LOSS:0.05809939652681351 | TEST LOSS:0.15978607535362244
EPOCH:10 | LOSS:0.04778777062892914 | TEST LOSS:0.12164457887411118
EPOCH:20 | LOSS:0.04369696229696274 | TEST LOSS:0.10520964860916138
EPOCH:30 | LOSS:0.04020693153142929 | TEST LOSS:0.09418994188308716
EPOCH:40 | LOSS:0.03675461560487747 | TEST LOSS:0.08523067086935043
EPOCH:50 | LOSS:0.03331653028726578 | TEST LOSS:0.0769583135843277
EPOCH:60 | LOSS:0.02988108992576599 | TEST LOSS:0.06937279552221298
EPOCH:70 | LOSS:0.026451697573065758 | TEST LOSS:0.061100445687770844
EPOCH:80 | LOSS:0.023012878373265266 | TEST LOSS:0.05282806232571602
EPOCH:90 | LOSS:0.019579116255044937 | TEST LOSS:0.04524257034063339
EPOCH:100 | LOSS:0.016148053109645844 | TEST LOSS:0.03697019815444946
EPOCH:110 | LOSS:0.012709235772490501 | TEST LOSS:0.02869783714413643
EPOCH:120 | LOSS:0.009277129545807838 | TEST LOSS:0.021112333983182907
EPOCH:130 | LOSS:0.005844403989613056 | TEST LOSS:0.012839937582612038
EPOCH:140 | LOSS:0.0024408861063420773 | TEST LOSS:0.005976951215416193
EPOCH:150 | LOSS:0.00756120216101408 | TEST LOSS:0.008383870124816895
EPOCH:160 | LOSS:0.00756120216101408 | TEST LOSS:0.008383870124816895
EPOCH:170 | LOSS:0.00756120216101408 | TEST LOSS:0.008383870124816895
EPOCH:180 | LOSS:0.00756120216101408 | TEST LOSS:0.008383870124816895
EPOCH:190 | LOSS:0.00756120216101408 | TEST LOSS:0.008383870124816895

#My problem is that I don't understand why if I try to run this other code:
#model_1.eval()

with torch.inference_mode():
  y_preds = model_1(X_test)

y_preds[:10]


#I get this results:
tensor([[1.2945],
        [1.3046],
        [1.3147],
        [1.3248],
        [1.3349],
        [1.3450],
        [1.3551],
        [1.3652],
        [1.3753],
        [1.3854]])
```

That don't match the model's state_dict() at all. I also tried to do one code similar to this before and it worked so I don't understand what's wrong.

I have just started with machine learning so I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Apparently if I put X instead of X_test as argument of model_1 in y_preds it gives me the right values but if I try to run the code then I incur in a size problem between x and y.